# What is the story behind Robert Langdon's Mickey Mouse watch?

Tags: character, analysis, props, angels-and-demons, the-da-vinci-code

In [Angels & Demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_&_Demons_%28film%29) and [The Da Vinci Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Da_Vinci_Code_%28film%29), movies, the character Robert Langdon (*Tom Hanks*) wears a Mickey Mouse watch and when somebody asks about it he never answers (or did I miss it?). The watch doesn't suit his personality. What is the significance of the watch? Is it explained in the novels?

Comment: I have to agree with you. There is also some evidence on how Robert Langdon Loves his watch. The Points are: 1. **Losing His Watch**- In Dan Brown's latest novel; *Inferno* Robert Langdon Loses his watch and is clearly disheartened. There were quite a few points in the novel that clearly annotates that Langdon Really Loves his watch. The image of his beloved Mickey Mouse Watch Is Here:
!http://watchesinmovies.info/img/f/AngelsAndDemons_Mickey.jpg If you cannot see the watch clearly, the image depicted below is the exact watch used in the movies "The Da Vinci Code" and "Angles and Demons"
!http

Comment: Transhumanist Ray Kurzveil also has same watch, coincidense?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The vintage, collectors edition Mickey Mouse watch was a gift from Langdon's parents on his 10th Birthday. As per the book, Langdon has not owned any other watch after that.

Quoting directly from the book:

> Although its juvenile dial often drew odd looks, Langdon had never owned any other  watch; Disney animations had been his first introduction to the magic of form and color, and Mickey now served as Langdon's daily reminder to stay young at heart

Growing up after his **introduction to the magic of form and color**, when he started taking interest into symbols and like, he would have figured more about Walt Disney, who, he says that, was doing his best to pass on the Grail story to future generations, during a conversation with Sophie.

Again quoting from the book, about the further details he gave to Sophie about Walt Disney

> Throughout his entire life, Disney had been hailed as "the Modern-Day
>   Leonardo da Vinci." Both men were generations ahead of their times,
>   uniquely gifted artists, members of  secret societies, and, most
>   notably, avid pranksters. Like Leonardo, Walt Disney loved infusing
>   hidden messages and symbolism in his art. For the trained symbologist,
>   watching an early Disney movie was like being barraged by an avalanche
>   of allusion and metaphor.

This would have ensured that **Walt Disney** was and will always be a hero for Robert, and especially this watch would have been holding a very special place in his heart, which he said that introduced him to the world of magic, in the first place.

Comment: Answer was better than anything Dan Brown has written

Comment: You mention "the book", but the question mentions both *Da Vinci Code* and *Angels & Demons*. So from which book are those excerpts exactly?

Comment: By the mention of the character Sophie, I infer this is from *The Da Vinci Code* which makes the Leonardo da Vinci references more apropos

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the already existing answers mentioning the books, the watch is also adressed a little more in [*Inferno*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3062096/), the third film in the series.

During Robert's kidnapping at the beginning of the story he loses his watch on the street (but gets it back at the end). When he notices that he's missing it in Sienna's apartment, he mentions that it's **quite important to him and was a gift from his parents**.

Answer (score -5):

Tom Hanks is the voice of Woody from Toy Story, who is owned by Disney. When Vittoria asks Robert why his watch has Mickey Mouse on it, he says "Yeah, it's a long story" referring to Toy "Story". We then see Vittoria smiling in a shot. This is just a nice little hint at Tom Hanks work as Woody. There may be other meanings to it like in other comments, but I think that this is why it is being portrayed in a lighthearted way. Hope this helps.

Comment: But it's in book too, read other answer.